# How do I get a specific block of code to loop again until I want to exit?

Tags: python, loops

I'm making an AI assistant that can search things up,either through text or speech. I also want to program it to do other commands such as solve math problems. I want it so that it will do the same thing again and again,until the user types Exit, but I'm having problems while doing that.
This is my code

```
def taken():
    taker = input("Type 1 to Search,Type 2 to Solve Math Problem, Type Talk to use Voice Input")

taken()

while True():
    if "1" in taker:
         searcher = input("What would you like to Search?")
         webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=({})".format(searcher))
         print("Type Exit to do something else")
    if "Exit" in taker:
        break
        taken()


def talk_talk():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    with mic as source:
        print("Say Something")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        query = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(query)
        webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=({})".format(query))


if "Talk" in taker:
    talk_talk()
```

I get a bool error when I try to either of those things.

Comment: You need to make a [mre] and include the full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
```

don't add () after it beacause then python seraches for a function or method.
and in the loop body keep asking the user for input, and if the input is exit then exit.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix the while loop to not call True(), as it were a function, then if you want to keep being prompted, put the prompt within the loop

```
def taken():
    return input("Type 1 to Search,Type 2 to Solve Math Problem, Type Talk to use Voice Input")

while True:
    taker = taken()
    if "1" in taker:
```

and any code after a break within the loop is never executed